# MPLAB programing: Questions on USART initialization code

Tags: microcontroller, c, embedded, uart, mplab

I have just started using MPLAB for microchip Atmega128. I had a few questions regarding the following code segment for USART initialization which I found in the product documentation.

1. Do I need to declare variables like, `URRH`, `URRL`, `UCSRB` at the start of the program. The documentation didn't specify this but the compiler is giving me

> " 'UBRRH' undeclared (first use in this function) "
> error.

```
UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);
```

2. As I understand this, `RXEN` and `TXEN` are supposed to be 1 bit each, but then how is the above expression valid?

> 

```
#define FOSC 1843200// Clock Speed
#define BAUD 9600
#define MYUBRR FOSC/16/BAUD-1

void main( void )
{
     ...
     USART_Init ( MYUBRR );
     ...  
}
void USART_Init( unsigned int ubrr )
{
     /* Set baud rate */
      UBRRH = (unsigned char)(ubrr>>8);
      UBRRL = (unsigned char)ubrr;
     /* Enable receiver and transmitter */
      UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN);
     /* Set frame format: 8data, 2stop bit */
      UCSRC = (1<<USBS)|(3<<UCSZ0);
}
```

Comment: You may have to `#include` the correct header file where these variables are defined. Please see any sample programs that come with the IDE to know which one to include. Otherwise, search the installation folder for `.h` files to see if any file like `atmega128.h` header file is present.

Comment: I searched the net with keywords `mplab atmega ubrrh include file` and found two useful pages which give a clue to what include file to use. [This page gives step by step](https://onlinedocs.microchip.com/pr/GUID-7FEA628B-1FF6-4B3D-BD72-5C82445720D4-en-US-1/index.html?GUID-66468D10-B453-4208-AC34-F3CBD35EB2BD) procedure to start a new project with an automatically filled out template code file. [This one](http://maxembedded.com/2013/09/the-usart-of-the-avr/) gives a [link to code](https://pastebin.com/7kfELPgv) to UART usage. The header file missing in your code seems to be `avr/io.h`.

Comment: You had to include: `xc.h`

Comment: Kindly respond to the comments, and accept an answer as solution once it solved your problem. That's how this site works,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I need to declare variables like, URRH, URRL, UCSRB at the start of the program

These are likely to be pre-defined macros defined in a header file in the compiler library corresponding to the microcontroller you target. You have to find that header file and include it in your application code.

> `UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN)`;
>
> As I understand this, RXEN and TXEN are supposed to be 1 bit each, but
> then how is the above expression valid

These should be pre-defined macros as well, which represent the bit positions of `RXEN` and `TXEN` bits in the register `UCSRB`.

The expression `UCSRB = (1<<RXEN)|(1<<TXEN)` is used in the code to set the bits `RXEN` and `TXEN` in the register.

Suppose `RXEN` and `TXEN` are in the 0th and 1st bit positions, you have to write `0b00000011` to `UCSRB` register to enable both Receiver and Transmitter. The above expression does the same thing with shift operator and ORing, making it easy to read the intention of the code.

```
(1 << RXEN)               --> (1 << 0) --> 0b00000001
(1 << TXEN)               --> (1 << 1) --> 0b00000010
(1 << RXEN) | (1 << TXEN) ---------------> 0b00000011
```

Alternatively you could also have done:

```
UCSRB |= (1 << RXEN) ;
UCSRB |= (1 << TXEN) ;
```

Setting the bits of a register without affecting/changing the status of other bits.

Comment: Thanks. Can these macros also be defined directly using binary format like, UCSRB = 0b00001110

Comment: Also why did you use a binary or (' | ') when assigning value with the second method     [ UCSRB |= (1 << RXEN) ]. Does this imply that the new RXEN bit will be OR of the assigned value and the previously stored value

Comment: You can't redefine pre-defined macros if the header is already included. Most compilers throw it as error. But you can assign it any binary value.

Comment: Yes, that's right. It does UCSRB = UCSRB | (1  << RXEN). Advantage is that it doesn't affect existing values of the other bits of the register. It sets only RXEN bit.